# Minimum password length is not working in Linux (RHEL7)

Tags: linux, passwords, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6, pam

I have set minimum password length to 3 on my RHEL 7 system.
Still while using passwd I get error:

> BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 5 characters.

I have changed following parameters:

In `/etc/security/pwquality.conf`:

```
minlen = 3
```

And in `/etc/login.defs`:

```
PASS_MIN_LEN  3
```

How passwd is getting 5 as minimum length?
Which config file I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Read the manual http://linux.die.net/man/5/pwquality.conf . Minimum length cannot be set to a value lower than 6. And if credits are enabled—which is the default—the computed score can be higher than you compute yourself.

Comment: Can I disable the pwquality in pam module stack?

Comment: I am not an expert in the issue, I would experiment: `grep pwquality /etc/pam.d/*` and you will see where `pam_pwquality.so` is used. `/etc/pam.d/passwd` controls behaviour of `passwd` utility, `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` controls the behaviour of programs that use password authentication (e.g. `ssh`). try removing `pam_pwquality.so` from the password stanzas?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with a fresh CentOS 7.4 install

```
authconfig --passminlen=12 --update
```

The command changes the parameter

```
minlen = 12
```

in

```
/etc/security/pwquality.conf
```

While on an older machine (wich I can no longer recover) the same command set the minimum length to 6, even if minlen was set to a higher value

Try to check if you have in /etc/pam.d

```
[root@host pam.d]# cat passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   substack     system-auth

[root@host pam.d]# cat system-auth
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
[...]
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only
[...]
```